# Elements.xml Id substitution

Tags: visual-studio, feature, groups, user, elements-xml

I have a site column defined in an Elements.xml file in Visual Studio. The SharePoint project this is in does all sorts of initial configuration on the website. I need to set the `UserSelectionScope` to be a certain group, however this won't work unless the group already exists and I know the ID, which I do not because the group in question is create in code in the feature event handler.

Essentially, I am trying to capture all of the initial setup and configuration of this SharePoint site in a single feature/solution that doesn't require manual intermediate steps.

Does anyone know if it's possible to set the `UserSelectionScope` by doing some kind of lookup by name? If not, does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

http://jankrogh.blogspot.com/2012/03/setting-userselectionscope-of-user.html

Gets the group by name, and then calls the Id.

Comment: I was afraid this might be the only solution. Very poor maintainability having half of a site column being made in XML and half in code. Gotta love SharePoint...

Comment: Yeah, I've run into a similar situation before. Getting Guids dynamically is clunky, but achievable.

Answer (score 1):

A quick one I thought of:

Why don't you only create the Field in the Elements.xml and then set the `UserSelectionScope` property of that field in the Event Handler after the group is created?

You can use the following property from the Object Model:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduser.selectiongroup.aspx